# JavaScript input date convertion

Tags: javascript, regex, string, date, date-format

Is there any way to convert any date string (not necessarily current date) (could be any format) to specific date format in Javascript. Like converting "MM-DD-YYYY" or "ddMMYYYY" to "DD-MMM-YYYY"?
I know that from current date as var date = new Date(), we can get time and hours but what to do in case of existing date string like "31/01/1999" to "31-JAN-1999".
Given the input date string can be of any format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.

You should be able to do it with moment.js.

Ex.

```
moment("31/01/1999").formatWithJDF("dd - MM - yyyy");
```

Have a look here, https://momentjs.com/docs/ for more details.

Comment: Plain JavaScript no libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using [DateFormatter.js](https://cloned.jp/javascript/en/DateFormatter.html)

```
var date = new Date('2020-03-25 10:30:25');
var formatter = new DateFormatter();
displayFormat = 'D M d Y h:i:s';
var dateString = formatter.formatDate(date, displayFormat); // Wed Mar 25 2020 10:30:25
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by first checking the input date format with the arrays or Map of regex provided, then need to convert that format to JS accepted format ISO format. 
Once converted to ISO format this date now can be converted to any form with logic written for it in separate functions.